# Repeated pop-ups 'Safari wants to use the "login" keychain'

Tags: password, keychain

I get repeated pop-ups saying
[image: Safari wants to use the "login" keychain]

I then enter the password
[image]

But the system always keeps on telling me it's the wrong password, which I'm sure it's not
[image]

This is what the Details reveal:
[image]

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

I'm running OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: And this only happens in safari? You can open your Keychain otherwise! If yes, in the key chain look for safari forms autofill, and show password for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somewhere along the lines either your user account password has changed or your `login.keychain` has become corrupted.  By default Keychain is set to sync it's password with your user account's password, allowing it to unlock when you login to your account, which in turn provides applications & processes access to it's contents.  When you change your password in the Users & Accounts section of System Preferences it communicates the change to Keychain Access, which in turn updates the `login.keychain` password.

Problems like this typically arise when a user account password is changed outside of Users & Accounts in System Preferences, by using the *Reset Password* utility in each OS X installer or by some other means.  When you change the password using one of these alternate methods the change is not communicated to Keychain Access.  When you login and start using the system following one of these changes you will continuously receive prompts similar to the one you've posted.

There are a couple of methods for getting around this and getting things working properly again:

**The first method** is to try any possible passwords that you may have used in the past.  Keychain doesn't have a lockout mechanism that would lock you out after X many tries so feel free to try as many as you can recall.  Assuming this works, and it accepts one of the passwords, you can update the keychain password to match your login password.  This can be accomplished by opening Keychain Access (located in `/Applications/Utilities`), clicking on *Edit* in the menubar and choosing "*Change Password for Keychain 'login'*".  This will allow you to enter the original password (whichever one just worked for you) followed by the new password, which should be the same password you use for logging in and/or doing software updates.

**The second method** is to create a new keychain.  You can navigate to `/Users/~/Library/Keychains`, where `~` represents your user's short name, and locate the `login.keychain` file.  Change the name of this file to `login.keychainold` or something similar.  Once you've changed the name log out of your user and log back in.  Within a few seconds one of the many processes should detect that `login.keychain` no longer exists and prompt you to create one, possibly with the verbiage "reset to system defaults", follow the prompts to accomplish this.  When it asks for a password you will enter your login password, the same one you just used to log back in.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response (and sorry for my late response). It seems to work with your first solution, changing the password of the keychain.

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear you were able to update the password rather than having to kill off the whole keychain.

Comment: Yup, I was able to move the keychain to a different name using `$ mv login.keychain login.keychainold` and the prompt stopped appearing, and my sister's laptop is working again now, thanks.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.  Thanks!!!